# com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets, xstream

[EDITED]

The project i'm working on is a 3 folder project in Java J2EE with servlets and Hibernate for the persistance. The structure is as follow: - Admin -> the main program with the beans and HTML/CSS - Jar -> with the jars, Hibernate tools and classes - War -> with the Servlets

Between them, I use Xstream to share the classes and important info.

I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat 7.

Hope that with this all of you get the global idea.

This what the Xstream debugger said:

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0 : satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0
---- Debugging information ----
message             : satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0
class               : satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Usuario
required-type       : satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Usuario
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /list/Usuario[2]/terapeuta
class[1]            : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
version             : null
```

Links (I don't have enough reputiation for have more than 2 links):

Complete StackTrace: http://pastebin.com/6vXyD6hC
XML: http://pastebin.com/YM9q3uvq
Servlet: below, in the comment
Where the problem occurs: below, in the comment
Java classes: below, in the comment
If something is missing, ask and I'll put it here. Thanks for all!!!

Comment: MORE LINKS: - Servlet: http://pastebin.com/zJ62QzWA - Where the problem occurs: http://pastebin.com/6E8qL4Kc - Java classes: http://pastebin.com/zGra79AG

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet code you are are mentioning :

```
xstream.alias("Terapeuta", Terapeuta.class);
```

In XML file it is given as:

```
<terapeuta class="satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0" resolves-to="Terapeuta">
```

So in logs you are getting error as:

The exception in logs says:

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException:
>   satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0

it seems your class namein MXL should be `satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta`

```
satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0
```

Comment: So... I should change `xstream.alias("Terapeuta", Terapeuta.class)` for `xstream.alias("Terapeuta", Satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta.class)` ??

Comment: can you add all your class details to your question to understand the issue better

Comment: Folder added to dropbox, you can see the important classes there. The missing ones are meaningless in this issue (I think :P).

Comment: Looking in some other threads, I think the problem is in this line of the XML `<terapeuta class="satdata.musicoterapia.hibernate.Terapeuta0" reference="../../Usuario/terapeuta"/>` because is the same "terapeuta" that the first object have. But don't know how to solve it.